# How can show image at view from webroot

Tags: image, cakephp, upload

I am trying to show image at view from webroot in cakephp.
But *I* didn't get any image. Please help me;

Is this code correct

```
$this->Html->image('WWW_ROOT . img/upload/aswq.png', array('width'=>'200px'));
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use in this way to show image from webroot folder. just notice that `img` folder already included path in `html` helper

```
 echo $this->Html->image('upload/aswq.png', array('width' => '200px','alt'=>'aswq'));
```

Will output:

```
<img src="/img/upload/aswq.png" alt="aswq" />
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: how about if the photo is in a different folder? webroot/files